# How can I insert an Image into a BLOB column by an insert statement in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, insert, blob

insert into my_image values(string name, Blob blob, String imageType);

I am having an image as .jpg. Here i dont want to use relative path lo_import('D:\image.jpg') .I want to convert the image into bytes and then i want to convert to blob.I want to insert this jpg image  using insert statement in postgres database.THis question is not a duplicate. This question is not asking to use relative path. Please read the question before you mark as duplicate.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-funcs.html consider using large objects instead

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have a `blob` data type. Your query will not work. You probably want `bytea`.